# Deploying EJB 2.0 in wildfly 30.0.0 error: Could not find method public abstract boolean javax.ejb.EJBObject.isIdentical

Tags: ejb, wildfly, ejb-2.x

We have a J2EE Webapp which uses EJB 2.0. Application is working fine in wildfly 10.0. We are working on upgrading to the latest stable version of wildfly 30.0.0. While deploying EJB 2.0 we are getting a method not found error with below stacktrace. We decompiled interface javax.ejb.EJBObject (which is loaded from javax.ejb-api-3.2.jar) confirmed that "boolean isIdentical(EJBObject obj) throws RemoteException" method is there but still we are getting "Could not find method public abstract boolean javax.ejb.EJBObject.isIdentical(javax.ejb.EJBObject)"

Here is the stacktrace.

```
2023-12-11 18:27:57,641 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Version] (MSC service thread 1-3) WELD-000900: 5.1.2 (Final)
2023-12-11 18:27:57,683 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component com.comp.api.service.soap.compAxisServlet due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
2023-12-11 18:27:57,692 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
2023-12-11 18:27:57,708 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component com.comp.support.viewer.LegacyJobExecute due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
2023-12-11 18:27:57,846 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."cde-ear.ear"."cde-ejb.jar".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."cde-ear.ear"."cde-ejb.jar".INSTALL: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of subdeployment "cde-ejb.jar" of deployment "cde-ear.ear"
    at org.jboss.as.server@22.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:178)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1617)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1580)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1438)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1363)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYEE0024: Could not configure component FormDistSessionCommitEJB
    at org.jboss.as.ee@30.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.deploy(EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.java:79)
    at org.jboss.as.server@22.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:171)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYEJB0384: Could not find method public abstract boolean javax.ejb.EJBObject.isIdentical(javax.ejb.EJBObject) throws java.rmi.RemoteException from view com.comp.cde.distribute.bizlogic.DistributionCommit on Jakarta Enterprise Beans class FormDistSessionCommitEJB
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@30.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.session.SessionBeanObjectViewConfigurator.configure(SessionBeanObjectViewConfigurator.java:107)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@30.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.DefaultComponentViewConfigurator.configure(DefaultComponentViewConfigurator.java:92)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@30.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.deploy(EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.java:65)
    ... 9 more
```

What could be the reason for this error and how can we fix it?

Comment: Basically it says, Your WELD system could not start three components in "cde-ejb.jar" at the INSTALL phase and it could not "configure" (probably deployment descriptor or version issue) the component "FormDistSessionCommitEJB" (it probably has the methods that were wanted.)

Comment: FormDistSessionCommitEJB appears from a quick google to be part of the customization classes in your app, it would be best to see what the class maps to particularly javax or jakarta if it is legacy.

Comment: You shouldn't be providing EJB API/impl via the webapp when the server already provides it out the box. Get rid of `javax.ejb-api-3.2.jar` file in webapp (and all others representing JEE API/impl already provided by server) and migrate `javax.*` to `jakarta.` and retry.

Comment: It won't work as WildFly 30 is JakartaEE 10 and EJB 2 are Java E so you won't have the proper packages.